# 2 dependent scheduled tasks, the second looks for a recent version of a file before executing

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, monitoring, scheduling

I have 2 batch processes that are dependent and both scheduled in close succession to one another on separate servers.  Right now they run when scheduled and the process is "timed" so that the first is complete before the second one starts.

The problem: sometimes they execute overlapped in time.

How can I have the second process look in a folder for a file written to the folder by the first process and check the files date and compare it to today, then execute when the file shows up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one bat have at the bottom

```
waitfor /s servernameofotherbat /SI OtherBatYouCanRun
```

And the other at the top

```
waitfor OtherBatYouCanRun
```

And for help

```
waitfor /?
```

Schedule at same time. Second will wait for first to finish.